# Use absolute paths for Meteor resources instead of relative paths

Tags: javascript, meteor

So all the links in the `<head>` in my development environment point are relative `<script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/meteor.js"></script>`. Is there any way to prepend that with the correct url? I.e. `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://example.com/packages/meteor.js"></script>`?

Comment: Why are you using ```<scripts>``` in any of your html? Meteor doesn't really require you to do this. Meteor is designed to load scripts by itself

Comment: [screenshot](http://imgur.com/qOjeXwG)

I'm not. When Meteor compiles all of its files it adds a bunch of script tags to the header to load in the javascript. I am trying to figure out how to prepend that path to make it an absolute path instead of relative.

Comment: I'm sorry, but at the moment I fail to understand why you're trying to achieve that.